# How do you cluster annotations with v10 of the MapBox iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

How is clustering done with v10 of the Mapbox iOS SDK? And can I use ViewAnnotations to show custom views for clusters?

In short, I am trying to cluster annotations on a Mapbox MapView, and show a custom UIView at each cluster. Something like the example shown [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/legacy/maps/examples/clustering/) in the Mapbox documentation for v6.x.

[image]

After looking through the iOS SDK guides and the documentation, it's unclear how to do this. There's even a section called "Migrate to v10", which seems to cover all the differences between v6.x and v10, *except* for how to cluster data. Before v10 of Mapbox (with v6.x), it seems you would use MGLPointFeatureCluster, but I can't find anything covering clustering with v10.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this feature is now built-in. I added a variety of annotations in different locations and it automatically grouped them into clusters when zooming in/out. No custom code is needed :)

Comment: Do you have any idea about getting url based image in unclustered layer?

Comment: Do you know how to play with settings ? distance min to cluster points, custom images etc ?

Comment: What if your clustered annotations have a different view?